# SSH Tunnel Stopped Working after a couple days

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

I'm running a Debian machine running an SSH Server connected to my home internet. it was working fine a day ago but now it stopped working for sum reason.
This is the command I'm using. It worked just fine before. I'm connecting to the debian machine via a mac and am using Firefox. It just keeps loading and never stops.

```
ssh -D 443 -C -v -N -i /Users/anonymous/.ssh/id_rsa anonymous@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 443
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:443 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 443.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 443.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 7: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 8: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 9: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 10: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 443 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 11: new [dynamic-tcpip]
```

Comment: I'm still at a loss of why it won't work. It worked before and I haven't changed anything.